# MVVM Discards the Collection in the ObservableCollection/List

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, microsoft-metro

hello guys im currently having troubles in finding the root cause why the ViewModel Discards my ObservableCollection i have this code in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<PersonData> _personData;

        public ObservableCollection<PersonData> PersonData
        {

            get
            {

                if (_personData == null)
                {
                    _personData = new ObservableCollection<PersonData>();

                }


                return _personData;

            }
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _personData, value);
            }
        }
```

if the _personData is null a new ObservableList is Instantiated, that is the only instantiation that i did, nothing else. and every time that i navigate away or change pages and return to the listview the collection disappears. is there any chance that i have forgotten to remove or to add? i have been asking from different forums but still no proper answer, and also i have tried many solutions that i can think of but still no progress. can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate away from page - this page with associated viewmodel should be destroyed - that's why your ObservableCollection disappear. If this page is "most-used" page in application you might consider to make your ViewModel singleton (preferably by some service locator pattern- check out this: [MVVM - IOC Containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx)) so it won't be cleaned on navigation.